# can some help understand this objdump of c

Tags: c, assembly, dump, objdump

```
08048544 <compare_password>:
 8048544:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048545:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048547:   83 ec 38                sub    $0x38,%esp
 804854a:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 804854d:   89 45 d4                mov    %eax,-0x2c(%ebp)
 8048550:   65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048556:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048559:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 804855b:   c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%ebp)
 8048562:   c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048569:   eb 22                   jmp    804858d <compare_password+0x49>
 804856b:   8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 804856e:   03 45 d4                add    -0x2c(%ebp),%eax
 8048571:   0f b6 10                movzbl (%eax),%edx
 8048574:   8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 8048577:   05 44 a1 04 08          add    $0x804a144,%eax
 804857c:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%eax),%eax
 804857f:   31 c2                   xor    %eax,%edx
 8048581:   8d 45 ea                lea    -0x16(%ebp),%eax
 8048584:   03 45 e0                add    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 8048587:   88 10                   mov    %dl,(%eax)
 8048589:   83 45 e0 01             addl   $0x1,-0x20(%ebp)
 804858d:   83 7d e0 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048591:   7e d8                   jle    804856b <compare_password+0x27>
 8048593:   c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)
 804859a:   eb 2c                   jmp    80485c8 <compare_password+0x84>
 804859c:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
 804859f:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 80485a1:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
 80485a4:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 80485a6:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
 80485a8:   03 45 e0                add    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 80485ab:   05 e0 a0 04 08          add    $0x804a0e0,%eax
 80485b0:   0f b6 10                movzbl (%eax),%edx
 80485b3:   8d 45 ea                lea    -0x16(%ebp),%eax
 80485b6:   03 45 e0                add    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 80485b9:   0f b6 00                movzbl (%eax),%eax
 80485bc:   38 c2                   cmp    %al,%dl
 80485be:   75 04                   jne    80485c4 <compare_password+0x80>
 80485c0:   83 45 e4 01             addl   $0x1,-0x1c(%ebp)
 80485c4:   83 45 e0 01             addl   $0x1,-0x20(%ebp)
 80485c8:   83 7d e0 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0x20(%ebp)
 80485cc:   7e ce                   jle    804859c <compare_password+0x58>
 80485ce:   83 7d e4 08             cmpl   $0x8,-0x1c(%ebp)
 80485d2:   7e 07                   jle    80485db <compare_password+0x97>
 80485d4:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 80485d9:   eb 05                   jmp    80485e0 <compare_password+0x9c>
 80485db:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80485e0:   8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
 80485e3:   65 33 15 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%edx
 80485ea:   74 05                   je     80485f1 <compare_password+0xad>
 80485ec:   e8 2f fe ff ff          call   8048420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 80485f1:   c9                      leave  
 80485f2:   c3                      ret    

080485f3 <main>:
 80485f3:   55                      push   %ebp
 80485f4:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80485f6:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80485f9:   83 ec 30                sub    $0x30,%esp
 80485fc:   65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048602:   89 44 24 2c             mov    %eax,0x2c(%esp)
 8048606:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048608:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
 804860f:   00 
 8048610:   8d 44 24 10             lea    0x10(%esp),%eax
 8048614:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048617:   e8 f4 fd ff ff          call   8048410 <gettimeofday@plt>
 804861c:   8b 54 24 10             mov    0x10(%esp),%edx
 8048620:   8b 44 24 14             mov    0x14(%esp),%eax
 8048624:   0f af c2                imul   %edx,%eax
 8048627:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 804862a:   e8 21 fe ff ff          call   8048450 <srand@plt>
 804862f:   e8 3c fe ff ff          call   8048470 <rand@plt>
 8048634:   89 44 24 18             mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)
 8048638:   8b 4c 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%ecx
 804863c:   ba 67 66 66 66          mov    $0x66666667,%edx
 8048641:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
 8048643:   f7 ea                   imul   %edx
 8048645:   c1 fa 02                sar    $0x2,%edx
 8048648:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
 804864a:   c1 f8 1f                sar    $0x1f,%eax
 804864d:   29 c2                   sub    %eax,%edx
 804864f:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 8048651:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
 8048654:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 8048656:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
 8048658:   89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
 804865a:   29 c2                   sub    %eax,%edx
 804865c:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 804865e:   89 44 24 18             mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)
 8048662:   8b 54 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%edx
 8048666:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 8048668:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
 804866b:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 804866d:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
 804866f:   8d 90 60 a0 04 08       lea    0x804a060(%eax),%edx
 8048675:   b8 c0 87 04 08          mov    $0x80487c0,%eax
 804867a:   89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 804867e:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048681:   e8 7a fd ff ff          call   8048400 <printf@plt>
 8048686:   b8 da 87 04 08          mov    $0x80487da,%eax
 804868b:   8d 54 24 22             lea    0x22(%esp),%edx
 804868f:   89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 8048693:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048696:   e8 e5 fd ff ff          call   8048480 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
 804869b:   8d 44 24 22             lea    0x22(%esp),%eax
 804869f:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80486a3:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80486a7:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80486aa:   e8 95 fe ff ff          call   8048544 <compare_password>
 80486af:   89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
 80486b3:   83 7c 24 1c 01          cmpl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
 80486b8:   75 0e                   jne    80486c8 <main+0xd5>
 80486ba:   c7 04 24 dd 87 04 08    movl   $0x80487dd,(%esp)
 80486c1:   e8 6a fd ff ff          call   8048430 <puts@plt>
 80486c6:   eb 0c                   jmp    80486d4 <main+0xe1>
 80486c8:   c7 04 24 f2 87 04 08    movl   $0x80487f2,(%esp)
 80486cf:   e8 5c fd ff ff          call   8048430 <puts@plt>
 80486d4:   8b 54 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%edx
 80486d8:   65 33 15 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%edx
 80486df:   74 05                   je     80486e6 <main+0xf3>
 80486e1:   e8 3a fd ff ff          call   8048420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 80486e6:   c9                      leave  
 80486e7:   c3                      ret    
 80486e8:   90                      nop
 80486e9:   90                      nop
 80486ea:   90                      nop
 80486eb:   90                      nop
 80486ec:   90                      nop
 80486ed:   90                      nop
 80486ee:   90                      nop
 80486ef:   90                      nop
```

Comment: Lol. No but really you should format that correctly. One instruction per line (normal assembly format). And what exactly is your question? "Understand this objdump" is rather vague.

Comment: We are not machines. We cannot and will not attempt to read your code and adequately accommodate you.

Essentially, you didn't even pose a question.

Comment: What app are you trying to crack?

Comment: The function looks not too complicated. I guess its a simple cracking tutorial. If you have a question we can help you for sure.

Comment: this was a class project last semester. we had to find passwords in this dump file but i couldn't. so, can someone help.

Comment: You can try to find an equivalent implementation in C. If you have this it will be very soon clear what kind of passwords are accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, learning assembly code from scratch will take some time and effort, but there's no harm in getting the basics.

Each line of this output contains three parts:

1. The offset in the file where that piece of code is (in hex)
2. The bytes that make up that piece of code (each in hex, again)
3. The assembly language form of that code (basically reverse-translated from the bytes).

You can generally read the flow of the program through the last column.  Instructions like JMPs will refer to other locations, which may or may not be nearby in the code.  They may be presented in a labelled form like:

```
jmp    804858d <compare_password+0x49>
```

That says, jump to offset `0x804858d`, so you can find that value in the first column.  The label says that this is offset `0x49` after `compare_password`.

If you don't know what most of the instructions do, well, they mostly move, combine and compare individual words of memory and register.  Even when you learn what each code does, understanding what it does in the context of this particular program can be hard.  And you generally need to know the location of other important pieces of data when the program will be running to know what the effect will be.

There are lots of resources for learning computer programming at the level of debugging, assembly language and dissassembly, but I will leave it to others to refer you.  If you really want to learn, a good way is to write your own simple program in C, and compile it to assembly.  Then compare the C and assembly output side-by-side, figuring out how the C statements have been translated into instructions.